# Pascal set acts weirdly

Tags: delphi, pascal

I don't understand why this code doesn't work properly:

```
program selection;
var 
    n : integer;
begin
    readln(n);
    if (n in [100..1000]) then writeln('Selected!');
    readln;
end.
```

this works fine for me with values between 1 and 233, if I enter 233, or more, the writeln.. doesn't get executed. This is very strange. I've also tried with other values, and the result is more or less the same, with only difference being the value it fails on.

Comment: A limitation on sets is that they can hold up to 255 elements. Are you sure about 233 ...

Comment: Rob has answered the direct question here; one wonders, however, why you are using a set here in the first place.  Why not `if (n >= 100) and (n <= 1000)` ?

Comment: It seems perfectly reasonable to want to use set notation here, @J... I'd prefer it, if it worked reliably.

Comment: I could use comparison, but I really wanted to do this with sets, as sets are what I want to learn to use right now. If there is no good solution to this problem, I'll just go back to using comparisons again..

Comment: Sometimes, one of the lessons about how to use a feature is what its limitations are. You've now learned a limitation of sets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delphi sets only go up to 255; a set with a maximum value of 1000 doesn't work. I'm a little surprised your code compiled.

When truncated to 8 bits, the value 1000 is 232, which explains why values larger than that fail.

Instead, you can use the [`InRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.InRange) function; it uses closed ranges just like set constructors.

```
if InRange(n, 100, 1000) then ...
```

You can also use plain old inequality operators to test whether the value lies in the given range:

```
if (100 <= n) and (n <= 1000) then ...
```

Finally, you can use a `case` statement. Case-statement selectors aren't sets, so they're not subject to the same rules as sets.

```
case n of
  100..1000: begin ... end;
end;
```

The downside is that it looks a little clumsy when there's only one case branch.

Comment: Ok, but aren't they supposed to act like intervals for arrays?

array[1..1000] of integer; 

would work. What are your suggestions on this matter?

Comment: The `..` operator can be used to define sets, and it can be used to define subrange types. In an array definition, it's defining a subrange type; sets are not involved there at all.

Comment: I'll try the test option. This is actually the way I wanted to use sets in the first place. :)

Comment: Ok, the case n of worked fine, however, I'm not sure as to why it doesn't have the same problem as when using the "if" way. Aren't those the same sets?

Comment: `InRange(n, 100, 1000)` is the way I'd do this in an if statement. Defined in the `Math` unit.

Comment: And if you really want large sets there is always TBits.

Answer (score 7):

[Rob has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682141/pascal-set-acts-weirdly/15684774#15682315) why you cannot use Delphi sets for what you need. I would also stress that a `set` is a very heavyweight type to store what amounts to an interval. Once this is recognised, it makes sense to use a function like `InRange` which operates on intervals.

As a fun exercise, you can write a simple record that represents an interval. And then you can use operator overloading to implement an `in` operator that will test for interval inclusion. This allows you to use the readable notation, and have the natural storage for an interval. And of course there are no constrains on element size.

Here is the simple demonstration:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TInterval = record
  public
    Low: Integer;
    High: Integer;
  public
    class operator In(const Value: Integer; 
      const Interval: TInterval): Boolean; inline;
  end;

class operator TInterval.In(const Value: Integer; 
   const Interval: TInterval): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Value>=Interval.Low) and (Value<=Interval.High);
  // or implement with a call to Math.InRange()
end;

function Interval(Low, High: Integer): TInterval; inline;
begin
  Result.Low := Low;
  Result.High := High;
end;

begin
  Writeln(25 in Interval(10, 100));
  Writeln(125 in Interval(10, 100));
  Writeln(2500 in Interval(1000, 10000));
  Writeln(12500 in Interval(1000, 10000));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Lovely syntactic sugar. How does this compares, performance-wise, with `(n >= low) and (n <= high)`?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera The code in this answer is heavier than `Math.InRange` and the test in your comment.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Maybe. I quite like `InRange()` myself.